# Gcc configuration error

Tags: gcc, configure

I am trying to build GNU toolchain for OpenRISC by following the guide given at http://openrisc.net/toolchain-build.html#_stage_1_gcc on Fedora Virtual Box Image.

I am getting error saying

```
Configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ../gcc-svn/config.sub
```

when I try to configure gcc using the command.

```
../gcc-svn/configure --target=or32-linux --prefix=$PREFIX    \
--disable-libssp --srcdir=../gcc-svn --enable-languages=c      \
--without-headers --enable-threads=single --disable-libgomp    \
--disable-libmudflap
```

The full content of config.log is as below

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../gcc-svn/configure --target=or32-linux --prefix= --disable-libssp --srcdir=../gcc-svn --enable-languages=c --without-headers --enable-threads=single --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = localhost.localdomain
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.11.7-300.fc20.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Mon Nov 4 15:07:39 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/adminuser/toolchain/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/or32-elf/bin/
PATH: /home/adminuser/.local/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/bin
PATH: /home/adminuser/MINSOC/tools/or32-elf/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2427: error: cannot run /bin/sh ../gcc-svn/config.sub

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=or32-linux

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD=''
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD=''
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK=''
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC=''
CC_FOR_BUILD=''
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD=''
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GCJ_FOR_BUILD=''
GCJ_FOR_TARGET=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LD_FOR_BUILD=''
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD=''
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD=''
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../gcc-svn/configure --target=or32-linux --prefix= --disable-libssp --srcdir=../gcc-svn --enable-languages=c --without-headers --enable-threads=single --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD=''
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD=''
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs=''
build_cpu=''
build_libsubdir=''
build_noncanonical=''
build_os=''
build_subdir=''
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor=''
clooginc=''
clooglibs=''
compare_exclusions=''
config_shell=''
configdirs=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host=''
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu=''
host_noncanonical=''
host_os=''
host_subdir=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libelfinc=''
libelflibs=''
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
pplinc=''
ppllibs=''
prefix=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='or32-linux'
target_alias='or32-linux'
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs=''
target_cpu=''
target_noncanonical=''
target_os=''
target_subdir=''
target_vendor=''
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag=''
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 2
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /bin/sh ../gcc-svn/config.sub`?

Comment: Include the lines prior to the error.

Comment: ls -l /bin/sh ../gcc-svn/config.sub gives lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Nov 7 2013 /bin/sh -> bash

Comment: And no output for `config.sub`?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx. 1 admin admin 36578 Jan 10 22:47 ../gcc-svn/config.sub

Comment: @ChethanN put further/updated informatoin in the question, not in comments.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work. Have a look at https://github.com/openrisc/or1k-gcc

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dos2unix` command.

In the directory in which config.sub is present write:

```
dos2unix config.sub
```

and then try to configure again